# Data Structure Equivalent to hashset but with these changes?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset

I am not able to use hashset in my scenario. Because there is no functionality of retrieving the object if the HashSet contains it. 
My implementation of HashSet is such that the 'equals()' checks only for a certain property of  the object. The other properties may vary. So, if an object **contains()** the object that I am searching for, i.e if the particular property matches, I want to retrieve the object and compare the other properties. But there is not function to retrieve the object, only a function to remove it is there.

Is there any altervative to it that can suit my requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hash map instead eq `HashMap<Your_Class, Your_Class>` which has get method

Comment: Is there any such alternative for a PriorityQueue? Even that does not have a getMethod.

Comment: But PriorityQueue is heap data structure implementation. From that structure you should only get element on top(min or maximum depending on PQ type) You can use those two methods for your needs:

- peek()
Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

- poll()
Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

Comment: But peek() only retrieves the object at the top of the tree. I want to retrieve an object if it is present in the PriorityQueue and  compare some other properties. I use the poll() functionality also.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) You dont use PQ for right problem. Maybe you can combine two data structures for your problem: HashMap for faster retrieving, PQ for retrieving minimal element

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider Interner pattern. [There are libraries that already have it](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html).

Guava version is thread-safe which is probably bad for performance...